# Failed to load API definition in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I am moving to Spring doc open Api and trying to hit the URL. I am getting the below error and logs from console.

URL : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?url=v3/api-docs

Logs :

```
2020-03-24 13:21:03.930 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-ui/index.html?url=v3/api-docs", parameters={masked}
2020-03-24 13:21:03.931 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"]
2020-03-24 13:21:03.933 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED
2020-03-24 13:21:03.992 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-ui/v3/api-docs", parameters={}
2020-03-24 13:21:03.993 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"]
2020-03-24 13:21:03.994 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-03-24 13:21:03.994 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-03-24 13:21:03.994 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-03-24 13:21:03.995 TRACE 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 matching mappings: [{ /error}, { /error, produces [text/html]}]
2020-03-24 13:21:03.995 TRACE 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2020-03-24 13:21:03.996 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2020-03-24 13:21:03.997 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Mar 24 13:21:03 EDT 2020, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available,  (truncated)...]
2020-03-24 13:21:03.998 DEBUG 32622 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

I do see my JSON Response when i try to open the below URL.

http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs

Comment: Maybe Swagger UI default URL is http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html ? Just try.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue today accessing a swagger URL like the following:

- http://localhost:6050/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#/

The web browser showed the page:

[image]

After I add the path `/v3/api-docs` into the page text field and click on explore button the documentation shown.

[image]

Looking to the [springdoc-openapi configuration](https://springdoc.org/springdoc-properties.html) I could see the default swagger ui path is `/swagger-ui.html` so when I acessed the following URL:

- http://localhost:6050/swagger-ui.html

It worked.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using security, or something like security you should permit "../v3/api" files.
I use like that

`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger/**","/v3/**").permitAll();`

Comment: authorizeRequests is deprecated in spring boot 3

Answer (score 3):

There could be the reason like when we start using spring security even then also we won't be able to access swagger-ui, here is what i tried and it started working.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/register").permitAll().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.apply(new JwtTokenConfigurer(tokenProvider));
}
```

Comment: this solution fixed my problem by adding the code in class `WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Answer (score 2):

Yes the URL to refer was incorrect. I tried with the new URL and it worked fine.

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/v3/api-docs&validatorUrl=

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring-security you have to include the config path in your sercurity configuration.
What I did in my security config was to exclude those paths from websecurity.

```
    @Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an outdate version of `commons-lang3`. Once I updated it to the version `3.10` it worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
http.anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Can be treat as temporary solution

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. You are allowing all requests to your service

Comment: That's why mentioned as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring security then add below config path security config file

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**","/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

in `springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-app` in your maven project try to change the path of swagger and try again
i hope it will works